# How to code for grouping email in conversations

Tags: .net, gmail, email

...similar to gmail !

Now it's easy enough to lump them together when the subject is (almost) same with additional prefixes ( re:, re: re:, ... ) perhaps

but you can include additional people when you reply etc. and they do show up in the original "conversation" thread

i haven't looked at the headers in a while but wondering if there are additional X-?????? headers that're being used or are part of some RFC/convention somewhere

any sample/example code that already does this would be great of course!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it all depends on how you save some of the data.

[Email Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Header_fields) already offer you:

> Message-ID: Also an automatically generated field; used to prevent multiple delivery and for reference in In-Reply-To: (see below).
>
> In-Reply-To: Message-ID of the message that this is a reply to. Used to link related messages together. This field only applies for reply messages.

Which can be used to link subsequent emails into a conversation group.

Comment: The references tag is a better indicator from prev. experience, however there were( are? ) differences in how various clients/servers generated/modified those tags, the question is to identify if there are any unifying techniques rather than the traditional continuous identify-build-identify issue-patch-build cycle

Comment: I highly doubt you find something different than that that works cross  [MUA's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent). Searching a bit I came to this interesting little [post](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-does-email-threading-work-in-gmail.html) that might give additional insight.

Comment: @Kumar: IIRC the References: header is from newsgroups (a.k.a. NNTP) and largely exists in mail due to Netscape Communicator.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an algorithm: http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html

Comment: very interesting post, though 10 years old. i wonder what the statistics are now.

Answer (score 4):

Im sure the most programs embedds metadata to the message so it can be tracked back to the original message when a reply is comming back. Anything other would be like guessing and as you point out, only subject and to/from is'nt going to cut it.

Outlook for example embeds thread-Index and Message-ID as metadata in the message wich can be used to track conversations between users no mather if other receivers are added later on in the conversation:

```
> Thread-Index: AcvvoZr5wUUl1mneRmCpi5P/XCjYWQ==  
> Message-ID: <D3B87CB5E0A0F54EABF3B2319E4120AF18146392@my.mail.server>
```

Comment: hmm, that's interesting, it'd be great if the servers ( gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc.) provide this or a similar "tag" !

Comment: I'm doing something similar for our internal ticket system which monitors a mailbox. There are several unique fields/IDs that are constant over replies/forwards of messages. I use these fields to group several e-mails into one ticket. I tested it with GMail and Outlook/exchange back then.